# Using gcc with Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, g++, cygwin

I want to learn to use shaders and therefore created a new C++ project on Netbeans (ver. 8.0.2).

I want to include the GLFW and the GLEW Library like stated in this tutorial: http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Creating-a-window

I think i included the librarys successfully. (Netbeans shows no error when using `#include <GL\glew.h>` or `#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>`, so i think it finds all the files).

My System: Windows 10 x64, using GNU gcc compiler via cygwin

Now here is the problem:
When i try to run the program, there is the following output:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Erik/programming/projects/FinallyShaders'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/finallyshaders.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Erik/programming/projects/FinallyShaders'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d"
gcc    -c -g -include /cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glew-1.13.0-win32/glew-1.13.0/include/GL -include /cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glfw-3.1.2.bin.WIN32/glfw-3.1.2.bin.WIN32/include/GLFW -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o main.c
cc1: fatal error: /cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glew-1.13.0-win32/glew-1.13.0/include/GL: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target 'build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Erik/programming/projects/FinallyShaders'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Erik/programming/projects/FinallyShaders'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 722ms)
```

It seems to fail because the gcc compiler (or more precisely the cc1 part of it) can't find the include-directory for the library. But, as stated, the path is correct. When using `cd <the path that cannot be found>` everything works and cygwin finds this path.

(My program does nothing but calling `printf()` until now, that shouldn't be the problem)

Does anybody know what this could mean and how to solve this?

Thanks for your help

Erik Brendel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your failing compiler commandline is:

```
gcc -c -g \
-include /cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glew-1.13.0-win32/glew-1.13.0/include/GL \
-include /cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glfw-3.1.2.bin.WIN32/glfw-3.1.2.bin.WIN32/include/GLFW \
-MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d" \
-o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o main.c
```

To fix the reported error:

```
cc1: fatal error: /cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glew-1.13.0-win32/glew-1.13.0/include/GL: No such file or directory
```

it should be:

```
gcc -c -g \
-I/cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glew-1.13.0-win32/glew-1.13.0/include/GL \
-I/cygdrive/C/Users/Erik/programming/Libraries/glfw-3.1.2.bin.WIN32/glfw-3.1.2.bin.WIN32/include/GLFW \
-MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d" \
-o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o main.c
```

You have confused the compiler options `-include` and `-I`. See [the documentation of
these options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)
Here is a [pretty good introductory tutorial to the use of GCC](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)

In the Netbeans project properties, the include search-directories should be
entered in **Build** -> **C Compiler** -> **Include Directories**, not **Include Headers**.

Comment: Thank you, that actually removed that error. It is just weird that Netbeans doesn't know about how to use the gcc (I havent wrote this command line, it was generated by Netbeans automatically)

Is there a way to edit this in Netbeans settings? I wouldn't want to comple manually every time...

And sadly, the next error appears: In main.c I use `#include <GL/glew.h>`. This line now throwds the error, that glew.h isn't present (No such file or directory: GL/glew.h), even though the file _is_ there.
(`ls -al <include_path_ending_on_GL>` shows the file glew.h)

Comment: Oh ok this makes makes sense. I just haven't seen this option

Comment: But sadly my second problem remains: `#include <GL\glew.h>` throws the error that this file cant be found

Comment: If the solution of the posted problem has revealed another problem, you
may ask another question. On SO, it's one question at a time :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you configuring the proyect linker for Netbeans?? This means telling the IDE you will be using libraries that are not added by default with just the include command, for example the math.h library(remember you had to compile with -lm via command promp, it's the same thing).

This can be done by going to run-proyect configuration-customize-Linker-Libraries(you click on the button with says ...). [image]

Then you click on add pkgconfig library or standard(for something like math.h or pthread in unix systems), and search for the library you wish to add.
[image]

Comment: I think the required librarys are there. It looks like [this](http://imgur.com/lgVMZsL)